# Why are no curly brackets added to my JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Why is the below code not outputting curly brackets around the value of `json`? I thought JSON is always encapsulated inside brackets.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("some text into json", Formatting.Indented);`
```

The resulting JSON is now `"\"some text into json\""`  rather than `{ "\"some text into json\"" }`

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a basic, but perfectly clear question!

Comment: What's up with the downvotes without a comment giving me a chance to improve the question? The question is purposely extremely simple, as I see no reason to bloat it.

Comment: Guess that could be one reason @Filburt, will change it to code.

Comment: @Filburt you moght not have downvoted, but you voted to close a question that is IMHO perfectly on topic here - as it asks about the behavior of a json serializer...

Comment: @Spontifixus Yes, I voted it to be "simple ... error" but I'd bet there's plenty of duplicates to point to as well and I guess this is the major DV reason - it could have been easily researched by a 1k+ member. And it should be understood: It's not that the community is obliged to prove there's an existing answer - it's up to the asker to give evidence of research effort.

Comment: @Filburt possibly true, though I did not find any dupes in a quick search - not even in the proposals coming up when starting a new question with the exact same title...

Comment: @Filburt With my search terms on google I expected to find an answer within 1 minute. I didn't find any, therefore the question. If I knew the answer I would still post the question along with the answer as well, so that other people will find it easier in the future.

Comment: @Filburt, I hope this question gets reopened soon - and if it has we should remove this comment thread here, as it adds no value to the question...

Comment: @JimAho It's important to reference research effort to stand out against all the help vampires - there's a good answer and 2 reopen votes and no danger of loosing this question.

Comment: @JimAho hey Jim! Your question doesn't show research effort. It's a very simple question, which can basically self-answered with minimal research, that's why DV. SO is polluted with "too simple" questions. Close vote basically for the same reasons, I tend to close questions which shouldn't be asked at all, they have no real value for the community. Sorry if you feel mistreated. Injustice happens on SO, but usually not without reason.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin I hear what you're saying, and I agree to some extent. One thing I don't get however - are you saying SO is not a good fit for too simple questions? Assuming I did show some research, would the question by nature still be too simple to fit on SO?

Comment: Your desired result `{"some text into json"}` is invalid JSON.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error.  See http://www.json.org/ for examples of valid JSON.

Comment: @JimAho not at all. But it should show research or, at least, define the part you don't get. The question as it looks now (with "I thought JSON is always encapsulated inside brackets." added part) is much better than it was initially. SO is welcome to question of any level, provided with some thought work. SO is abused as an answer machine, there questions is thrown at it without any effort on the other side. For simple questions if you ask properly, you frequently find answer yourself in the process, at least it happened to me, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JimAho P.S. removed my DV and added UV now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you simply serialized a string. Thus the serializer returns just the serialized string, which, in JSON, is just the string enclosed in quotes:

```
"some text"
```

JSON only adds curly braces if you serialize an object:

```
{
    "someStringProperty": "some text"
}
```

Also note that the backslashes in your output result from Visual Studio encapsulating the whole string in quotes again and also escapes quotes within the string. The "real" values of the serialized string just use simple quotes. Thus Visual Studio would display the above JSON string as follows:

```
"\"some text\""
```

or

```
"{ \"someStringProperty\": \"some text\" }"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON](http://www.json.org/) stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" meaning that all data is represented as a single JavaScript object (a string that looks like a JavaScript code of the object, to be more correct).

That's why curly brackets are not mandatory, they are needed then necessary to represent complex object structure. `{ "some text into json" }` (I omit quote escape for clariness) is just plain syntax error for JavaScript compiler! You can have `{ "key": "value", "other key": "other value" }` objects, but a key without a value is error.

So the `"some text into json"` is the only possible correct JSON for the string object `"some text into json"`.